# Accelerated hashing on consumer-grade CPU?

Tags: hash, cryptographic-hardware

Question is a follow-up to [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/733/accelerating-sha-1). The question was about accelerating SHA1. I am writing an application, where I do have a choice of hash algorithm, as long as it's a strong one. I want to be able to use the one which could be CPU-accelerated on consumer grade AMD and/or Intel processors. Which one should I take?

Comment: No consumer CPU supports a hardware accelerated hash instruction, however Intel Haswell CPUs have AVX and BMI instructions, and can hit 0.6GB/s for SHA-512 (the obvious choice for security) or 1GB/s for SHA-1

Comment: BLAKE2b is about as close as you can get to a modern hashing algorithm that's CPU-accelerated.

Comment: Are you hashing many short messages, or few long ones? In the latter case you must use a tree hash to have any hope of parallelization.

Comment: @RichieFrame Almost no consumer CPU supports hardware accelerated hash instruction, as the [VIA Eden processors](http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/processors/quadcore/index.jsp) do. They are however not known particularly for speed, so the mileage may vary.